# Split words and insert it new table with counting these words

Tags: sql, plsql, group-by, split, oracle11g

I have the foolwoing table and data.
i need to:
1- split each sentence in each row into new row
2-count the words in each row based on last part of sentence based on soundex function

```
create table a (id number(9), words varchar(500));
insert into a values(1,'UK,LONDON,YEMEN,JOHN,CAIRO,OMAR ALI,EGYPT,Cairo,YEMAN,OMAR AMR ALI,LONDAN');
insert into a values(2,'UK,SUDAI,SUDAIN,AYHAM SHAHER YAFOOZ,ALI YAFOOZ');
insert into a values(3,'MALAYSIA, AHMED ALI,MALYSIAN');
```

expexted output

create table temp_words(id number(9),words varchar2(100), count_words number(9));

```
id            words                count_words
1              UK                     1
1            LONDON                   2
1            YEMEN                    2
1            CAIRO                    2
1            OMAR ALI                 2
1             JOHN                    1
2              UK                     1
2              SUDAI                  2
2          AYHAM SHAHER YAFOOZ        2
3               MALAYSIA              2
3              AHMED ALI              1
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

to split the data as you want you can use a "connect by" as a row generator.

```
SQL> with src as (select id,',' || words || ',' as words,
  2                      length(words) - length(translate(words, '.,', '.')) + 1 no_of_words
  3                 from a)
  4  select a.id,
  5         substr(a.words,
  6                instr(words, ',', 1, r) + 1,
  7                instr(words, ',', 1, r + 1) - instr(words, ',', 1, r) - 1) word,
  8         a.no_of_words
  9    from (select level r
 10            from dual
 11          connect by level <= (select max(no_of_words) from src)) d
 12         inner join src a
 13                on d.r <= a.no_of_words
 14   where a.no_of_words is not null
 15   order by a.id, d.r
 16  /

        ID WORD                 NO_OF_WORDS
---------- -------------------- -----------
         1 UK                            11
         1 LONDON                        11
         1 YEMEN                         11
         1 JOHN                          11
         1 CAIRO                         11
         1 OMAR ALI                      11
         1 EGYPT                         11
         1 Cairo                         11
         1 YEMAN                         11
         1 OMAR AMR ALI                  11
         1 LONDAN                        11
         2 UK                             5
         2 SUDAI                          5
         2 SUDAIN                         5
         2 AYHAM SHAHER YAFOOZ            5
         2 ALI YAFOOZ                     5
         3 MALAYSIA                       3
         3  AHMED ALI                     3
         3 MALYSIAN                       3

19 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a90d3/53)

```
select id,words,

case when i=0 then
SUBSTR(words,
   1,
case when INSTR(words,',', 1, 1)=0 
       then 100000
       else
       INSTR(words,',', 1, 1)-1
       end

   )    
ELSE

SUBSTR(words,
   INSTR(words,',', 1, i)+1,

   case when INSTR(words,',', 1, i+1)=0 
       then 100000
       else
       INSTR(words,',', 1, i+1)-INSTR(words,',', 1, i)-1 
       end

   )
END word,
i+1 COUNTWORDS

from a,
(
select * from
(
select 0 i from dual 
union 
select 1 i from dual 
union 
select 2 i from dual 
union 
select 3 i from dual
union 
select 4 i from dual 
union 
select 5 i from dual 
union 
select 6 i from dual
union 
select 7 i from dual
union 
select 8 i from dual
union 
select 9 i from dual
union 
select 10 i from dual
union 
select 11 i from dual
union 
select 12 i from dual
 )
  )
table_i

where 
  case when i>0 then INSTR(words,',', 1, i) 
  else 100000 end <>0 
order by id,i
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach(using `regexp_count` and `regexp_substr` regular expression functions):

```
SQL> with Occurence(oc) as(
  2    select level
  3      from ( select max(regexp_count(words, '[^,]+')) ml
  4               from a
  5            ) t
  6     connect by level <= t.ml
  7  )
  8  select id
  9       , word
 10       , count(word) over(partition by id, soundex(word) order by id) as count_words
 11    From ( select a.id
 12                , regexp_substr(words, '[^,]+', 1, o.oc) as word
 13             from occurence o
 14            cross join a
 15          ) s
 16            where s.word is not null
 17  order by id
 18  ;

        ID WORD                 COUNT_WORDS
---------- -------------------- -----------
         1 Cairo                          2
         1 CAIRO                          2
         1 EGYPT                          1
         1 JOHN                           1
         1 LONDAN                         2
         1 LONDON                         2
         1 OMAR ALI                       1
         1 OMAR AMR ALI                   1
         1 UK                             1
         1 YEMEN                          2
         1 YEMAN                          2
         2 ALI YAFOOZ                     1
         2 AYHAM SHAHER YAFOOZ            1
         2 SUDAI                          1
         2 SUDAIN                         1
         2 UK                             1
         3  AHMED ALI                     1
         3 MALAYSIA                       1
         3 MALYSIAN                       1

19 rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to insert your data as separate records. You can keep them as a concatenated string, if you like, but it'll just make your life very difficult. So:

```
create table words (
  id number,
  w  varchar2(100),
  s  varchar2(4)
);

create or replace trigger words_auto
  before insert or update on words
  for each row
begin
  select trim(upper(:new.w)), soundex(:new.w)
  into   :new.w,              :new.s
  from   dual;
end;

insert into words (id, w) values (1, 'UK');
insert into words (id, w) values (1, 'LONDON');
...
insert into words (id, w) values (3, ' AHMED ALI');
insert into words (id, w) values (3, 'MALYSIAN');
```

You could write a procedure to split your concatenated string and populate the `words` table appropriately. Note that I have created a trigger that normalises your input to uppercase, removing all extraneous whitespace and automatically produces the Soundex codes.

Now here's a question: You want to group words by their Soundex codes; however, how do you determine the baseline? For example, 'LONDON' and 'LONDAN' both have code 'L535', but how do you know which record is the 'main' one?... You can't, without further lookup tables! As such, the best you can do is to group by the Soundex codes. This doesn't have to be stored in a table and it makes more sense to be a view:

```
create or replace view word_counts as
  select   id,
           s soundex,
           count(w) count_rows
  from     words
  group by id,
           s;
```

Note that I've called the count field `count_rows` as it counts records, rather than distinct rows. That is: records of 'LONDON', 'LONDAN' and 'LONDON' will show with a count of 3, not 2 (which you might be expecting). Anyway, with your data, the view will look something like this:

```
id    soundex   count_rows
----- --------- -----------
1     U200      1
1     L535      2
...   ...       ...
3     M420      2
3     A534      1
```

As I say, that's really the best you can expect without further infrastructure.